# Finding lost bluetooth device

Tags: bluetooth, geolocation, maps, spotify, history

I was traveling from NY to Cleveland and I misplaced my Sennheiser Momentum TW's.
I used [Google My Activity](https://myactivity.google.com/item) to help see my phone activity, and I see Spotify was opened at 3:21pm which would suggest I still had them after my stopover at 3:03pm (according to Maps timeline). Is there anyway I can view the last time they were connected to my device?

All help is greatly appreciated!
More than welcome to some out of the box solutions!

Comment: try the notifications history widget https://nexus7.gadgethacks.com/how-to/unlock-hidden-notification-history-feature-your-nexus-7-tablet-0150162

Comment: Thanks for your response, I couldnt find that widget (using an s10)

Comment: this work for android 7.0 nougat: install QuickShortcutMaker, navigate to activity Settings - com.android.settings.Settings$NotificationStationActivity - Create shortcut